# CHECK variable usage in comparing of Strings?

Tags: c++

```
void display_a_student(char n[])
{

    cout<<"\nSTUDENT DETAILS\n";

    int check=0; ***** WHY ARE WE USING THIS CHECK ??????

    fp.open("student.dat",ios::in);
    while(fp.read((char*)&st,sizeof(student)))
    {
        if((strcmpi(st.get_ID_number(),n)==0))
        {
            st.show_student();
            check=1; ----> What is this ?
        }
    }

    fp.close();
    if(check==0)
        cout<<"\n\nStudent does not exist";
    getch();

}
```

I am not understanding this "check" in code ??
Please tell me the answer as soon as possible:)
          This is the code..

Comment: I hope this is not code from your C++ class, because it's bad. Very bad.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It's a flag. It's used here to check whether the user record exists. If you see this code,

```
if(check==0)
                cout<<"\n\nStudent does not exist";
```

you can see they check if it's zero & prints the string `"Student does not exist"`, which means zero is the default value. It would be set to 1 if student detail exists. That check is done in following code,

```
if((strcmpi(st.get_ID_number(),n)==0)) --> This will be true only if student record exists.
                {
                           st.show_student();
                           check=1; ----> The flag is set here.
                }
```

And finally, this flag need not be named as "check" always. you can have your own name.

Answer (score -1):

I think the coder try to use the check variable as a mechanism to tell whether any student record exist in the file at all..

If no student record is found.. then it will print the message:
cout << "Student does not exist";..